# How to copy values from uint2 to one vector in thrust?

Tags: vector, cuda, thrust

I am having values in `vector<uint2> results (size)` I just wanna copy the values of results.y alone to a `vector<int> count (size)`. How can I do this using `thrust::transform` function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare some kind of function object (it can be either `UnaryFunction` or `BinaryFunction` that will select second element from `uint2`. You can use lambda if you enable `--expt-extended-lambda` in nvcc:

`auto selector = [&]  __device__ (const uint2& pair) { return pair.y; };`

You can use function object instead:

```
struct Selector
{
    __host__ __device__ unsigned int operator()(const uint2& pair) 
    {
        return pair.y;
    }
};
```

And then use it in `thrust::transform`:

`thrust::transform(results.begin(), results.end(), count.begin(), selector);`

or

```
Selector selectorObject;
thrust::transform(results.begin(), results.end(), count.begin(), selectorObject);
```

Comment: And @Anbu as you are new to this site - if i helped you, mark my answer as solution.

Comment: yeah thank you. But I need one more clarification. If the results vector is in device as, uint2 results = NULL;cudaMalloc((void*) &results, sizeof(uint2) * size); unsigned count = NULL; cudaMalloc((void**) &count, sizeof(unsigned) * size);then how this transform function works to copy to 'count' here? @pSoLT